# Odd Shortened Syntax for Closures in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, syntax, closures

I'm trying to fully wrap my head around closures in Swift. I think I understand the basics. However, I ran into some odd syntax and would appreciate if someone can understand what it means.

I'm going to show the shortened syntax that I came across, but first I'll show how I would write this code *without* the shortned syntax. I think I understand everything that's going on in the following code, but I'll narrate it just to make sure :)

```
//function
func manipulate(numbers: [Int], using algorithm: (Int) -> Int){
    for number in numbers{
        let result = algorithm(number)
        print("Manipulating \(number) produced \(result)")
    }
}
//trailing closure syntax
manipulate(numbers: [1,2,3]){(number: Int) -> Int in
    return number * number
}
```

Okay, so we're basically declaring a function called manipulate that takes 2 parameters. One of these parameters is *numbers* and it is an array of Ints. The second parameter, known as *using* externally and *algorithm* internally is a closure, which takes an Int as a parameter, and returns an Int.

Okay cool, the function then goes through all the numbers in the array *numbers* and applies the result of calling the closure, *algorithm* on each number.

Okay, so that's what the function does, now, let's call it with trailing closure syntax.

What I did was call the function, *manipulate* and pass in the first parameter, *numbers*, and then, going by the trailing closure syntax, defined the closure that I'm going to be using. It's taking a parameter, which I called *number*, that is an Int, and it's returning another Int, number * number.

This code makes perfect sense to me.

Here's the variant that tripped me up. The definition of the function was exactly the same, but, the function was called in a way that I don't understand.

```
//function
func manipulate(numbers: [Int], using algorithm: (Int) -> Int){
    for number in numbers{
        let result = algorithm(number)
        print("Manipulating \(number) produced \(result)")
    }
}
//trailing closure syntax
manipulate(numbers: [1,2,3]){ number in 
    number * number
}
```

First of all, we're not specifying the type of the parameter that the closure takes, and we're also not specifying the type of the return value. Also, what does *number* even mean in this context when we're calling the function?

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain what's going on here. I'm pretty sure it's some idiomatic syntax in Swift, but I don't quite understand it.
Thanks!

Comment: In Swift you don't need to specify the type where it can be inferred.  Since the closure argument to `manipulate` takes and returns an `Int` Swift can infer that `number` is an `Int`.  Swift 5 allows you to omit the return statement (implicit returns) where a code block has only one statement.

Comment: Hmm interesting, so swift is inferring that number is the parameter for the closure?

Comment: Not exactly.  In your first example the parameter was also called `number`. In the second case the type, `Int` has been inferred instead of explicitly stated.  The compiler knows that whatever comes before the keyword `in` is to receive the parameter

Comment: Ohh okay, and the return type is also inferred? Interesting. Is this a common shorthand in Swift?

Comment: Yes.  No-one would code as per your first example.

Comment: Ah haha gotcha, thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way. Arrays has a map function which also does a similar thing but with less code. `let resultArray = myIntegerArray.map({ $0 * $0 })`

Comment: If you want I can write it as an answer and explain it.

Comment: All well explained in my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions Scroll down to where I start listing things you can omit and why.

Comment: Emre, I went through a few tutorials and figured out that syntax, but I was wondering, is that also common syntax in swift? Or do most people still pass in the parameters?

Comment: And thank you matt